# Jacobian of a rather long function

Tags: derivatives, jacobian

I am trying to calculate the Jacobian of a function but I don't know whether I got it right. The function is
$$
f(x)=\frac{F}{V}\cdot(x_{in}-x)+\beta\cdot(k_0\cdot e^{-E_a/x})\cdot(C_{A,in}+\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot(x_{in}-x))\cdot(C_{B,in}+\frac{2}{\beta}\cdot(x_{in}-x))
$$
where x is a scalar variable

Using the chain rule I calculated the Jacobian to be
$$
J=-\frac{F}{V}+\frac{\beta\cdot k_0\cdot E_a\cdot e^{-E_a/x}}{x^2}\cdot(-\frac{1}{\beta})\cdot(-\frac{2}{\beta})
$$

But I am pretty sure I got a wrong result by doing something wrong using the chain rule. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the product rule. The function takes the form$$f(x)=a(x)+b(x)c(x)d(x)$$and you wrote$$f'(x)=a'(x)+b'(x)c'(x)d'(x)$$but this is incorrect. Rather,$$f'(x)=a'(x)+b'(x)c(x)d(x)+b(x)c'(x)d(x)+b(x)c(x)d'(x)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just can't seem to get those derivatives right!